# Tensorflow installation - Consider adding this directory to PATH in R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow and it is installed as detailed bellow but I cannot use it. I don't understand but during the installation I got lot of warning message. Do I need to import the mentioned path somewhere?

```
WARNING: The script tensorboard.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Tensorflow is here, I can check using

```
py_discover_config("tensorflow"):
tensorflow:     C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p
```

but it does not work under R when I test it:

```
library(tensorflow)
> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
```

Comment: The error refers to the [`system PATH`](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) variable. Simply follow that guide to add the path suggested, and it should work as intended. You could also use `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), PathToTensorflow, sep = ';'))` before running `library(tensorflow)`. This only works for 1 session.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it is far from my skills. Could you give me an example of how to write this: Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), PathToTensorflow, sep = ';'))

Comment: I try this but change nothing: Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), "C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow", sep = ';'))

Comment: The error message has the path (`C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\Scripts`). While it looks weird, it likely works just to add this. But the path is likely stating the directory (unabbreviated) (needs checking on your end) `C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\R-Miniconda\envs\R-Reticulate\Scripts`.

Comment: You can think of the `PATH` as a variable, like `a = 3´. It is just that. It will contain a list of directories, and files, seperated by `;`, and this path is the standard method to give scripts/programs a direction in where to search for files they are looking for. Eg. If you execute a game on steam it might look in the `PATH` variable for a directory containing that game, and then execute that game. I think steam works a bit different but this is just to give an example. Adding to the path tells the programs to "hey, search this directory as well".

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for your detailed explain. I added the PATH and ran the following lines but still same error message Tensorflow not found even if it is detected when doing reticulate::py_config().library(usethis)
library(devtools)
library(reticulate)
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH')**** /tensorflow
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH')***** /scripts
use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)